# What minimum number (A) can be taken so that (A)^N is larger than the product of N numbers?

Tags: number-theory, statistics, inequality, algorithms

Given a sequence of **N** numbers say 2,8,4,7,6,5. How can we calculate a minimum number say **A** such that **A<sup>N</sup>** is greater than the product of 2*8*4*7*6*5 = **13440**?

So the minimum number satisfying the above condition is **5**.
As **5<sup>6</sup>** = **15625** which is greater than **13440**.
But **4<sup>6</sup>** = **4096** which is less than **13440**.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the job for the $N$-th root. It's defined the following way:

> The $N$'th root of a positive number $x$, written $\sqrt[N]x$, is the unique positive real number such that $(\sqrt[N]x)^N = x$.

In your example, we want the sixth root of $13440$. We put it into a calculator, and get approximately $4.88$. This means that $4.88^6\approx 13440$, which tells us that $5^6$ is larger, and $4^6$ is smaller than the product.

Comment: You want "the unique _positive_ real number such that" to avoid ambiguity between $4.88$ and $-4.88$ in this case ($N$ is an even natural number).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric mean will do it: in your case we have

> $\sqrt[6]{2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5} = (2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5)^{\frac{1}{6}} = 4.87603...$ so, as you noted, $5^6 > 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$ but $4^6 < 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$.

In general, if we take $N$ numbers $a_1,..., a_N$ then setting $b =\sqrt[N]{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_N}$ we have

$$b^N = a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_N$$ and so $x^N > a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_N$ for any $x>b$